# using url() for css background-image not working

Tags: css, laravel, sass

I'm using url() for css background-image. ie

```
background-image: url(../images/cart-icon.png);
```

But while rendering in frontend. It doesnot give full path to the image file.
[image]

the path should be

> http://localhost/project-name/public/images/wishlist-icon.png

please guide me. Thank You

Comment: your code is correct it will work on `top` level domain you need to remove `project-name/public` from url use `laragon` or `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

Inline css:

```
background-image: url('/images/wishlist-icon.png');
```

And external css (public/css/style.css):

```
background-image: url('../images/wishlist-icon.png');
```